# Can I define my own custom HTML Elements for use with css and js?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been reading all about these hot new *custom HTML elements* that you can make with today's browsers; It seems pretty interesting, to be honest. I've seen that the camp is out on this one, though; There's a lot of debate over whether to use them or not.

*But that's not my question!*

I've seen that in order to use custom HTML elements, you have to declare the element with javascript first; but I'm not finding this to be the case.

I simply ran an HTML document with the following code;

```
<div>
   <header-label>Text</header-label>
</div>
```

And it worked just fine in Chrome (`40`), FireFox (`40`), Internet Explorer 11, and Edge.

So I'm more confused than before; What is going on? Do I need to declare them, or not? Even `CSS` worked against it, as did jQuery selectors, angular directives; I couldn't find anything that led me to believe this was anything but a normal HTML element.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-custom-html-elements-2

Comment: Sorry, my bad... Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A) User-defined tags

You can use user-defined tags anywhere.

If you want to put `<header-label>` that's up to you.
There are also custom HTML5 attributes which are things like

```
<input name="q" placeholder="Go to a Website">
```

or

```
<input type="email">
```

I investigated further and read those blog post comments and learned about...

### B) HTML5 Custom Elements:

Per http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

These let you do things like

```
<hangout-module>
  <hangout-chat from="Paul, Addy">
    <hangout-discussion>
      <hangout-message from="Paul" profile="profile.png"
          profile="118075919496626375791" datetime="2013-07-17T12:02">
        <p>Feelin' this Web Components thing.</p>
        <p>Heard of it?</p>
      </hangout-message>
    </hangout-discussion>
  </hangout-chat>
  <hangout-chat>...</hangout-chat>
</hangout-module>
```

These would otherwise be ignored (though the content and valid tags within them will still render without issue), however you can add these elements as valid DOM elements with:

```
var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo');
document.body.appendChild(new XFoo());
```

You can also base a user-defined element on an existing element to extend it, e.g.

```
var MegaButton = document.registerElement('mega-button', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype),
  extends: 'button'
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to find out if this is truly creating a valid HTML element that won't bite me later, or if it is basically modern browsers way of gracefully ignoring something stupid.

Comment: By 'it works', I mean that the page renders and everything like I would expect it to, as if the new element is completely natural. I can select it with javascript, I can style it with CSS, I can find it in the dev tools, etc. I'm trying to figure out if this is doing the same thing as the custom elements.